# What is the most accurate instrument which can be used to measure frequency of radio waves without measuring wavelength and how accurate is it?

Tags: waves, frequency, radio-frequency, radio

I wanted to know if there's an instrument that accurately measures the frequency of radio waves as I'm working on something and I didn't get anything good on web.

Comment: What frequency range of radio waves do you want to measure? 100 kHz is a lot easier to measure than 100 GHz.

Comment: if lower frequency can be measured easily then thats good i guess and btw is should be small if any

Comment: What do you mean by "not measuring wavelength"?

Comment: Sry I meant direct frequency measurement, I got confused while writing the question

Answer (score 2):

You can easily buy a [frequency counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_counter) that measures frequencies up to a few gigahertz with accuracy better than 1 ppb (one "part per billion" or a relative error of $10^{-9}$).

If you need to measure higher frequencies you can consider *pre-scaling*. That is, use a frequency divider to lower the frequency by an integer divisor, and then measure the lower frequency with a frequency counter.

If you need greater accuracy, you can consider using a higher-quality reference clock for your frequency counter. The ultimate reference would be an atomic clock at one of the national standards labs.